# Variable when called outside of an on_message function is not able to be referenced inside the function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a code called "saynum" with a parameter of amount(which is a natural number.) The way the command is supposed to work is it counts the number of messages since you ran the command, and sends the number onto discord. I have a block though. When trying to run an `async def on_message(message)` (with @bot.event of course) and calling a variable outside of that, I am not able to reference the variable from outside the on_message function. Is there a workaround to this? This question will probably get downvoted.

If there is not a workaround to this, then is it possible for that command to work? I have no idea how to approach it in another way.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import sys
import traceback


Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~', case_insensitive=True)
client.remove_command("help")

@client.command()
async def saynum(ctx, amount):
    num = 0
    if amount.isdigit():
        if int(amount) < 1:
            await ctx.send("Please put an integer greater than 1.")
        else:
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        num += 1
        await ctx.send(num)
```

Oh, one last thing. My python version is 3.6.6 and I am using discord.py rewrite if you couldn't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the line `num += 1` put `nonlocal num`
This lets python know the scope of your variable (in this case, outer)